# Rails mysql2 undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, migrate

I know that was a million times here but tried everything and I am still getting this error:

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is the gem list (not all):

```
activemodel (3.2.8)
activerecord (3.2.8)
activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
builder (3.1.3, 3.0.3)
bundler (1.2.1)
mysql2 (0.3.2)

rails (3.2.8)
rails_apps_composer (2.2.10)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
therubyracer (0.10.2)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.1.3)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.3.0)
```

I have tried with all versions of mysql2 (from 0.2.7 to 0.3.2)

Edit (database file):

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: tripwall
  username: root
  password: pass
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Comment: Can you include your database.yml file?

Comment: Have you tried: bundle update activerecord-jdbc-adapter and bundle update mysql2

Answer (score 23):

Both answers from Sean and Mitch contribute to the solution:

- Version of mysql2 gem should be 0.3.11 and above, and
- activerecord-mysql2-adapter should be removed from gemfile.

Wanted to make it clear that:

1. Your gemfile should contain the following line (remove activerecord-mysql2-adapter alone):

   > gem 'mysql2'
2. `gem list` should output the following line:

   > activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)
   >
   > mysql2 (0.3.11)

Edit:

I also got the below error when I tried to open the index of a scaffold-generated model:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

I had to restart the rails server; and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 13):

I just remembered what I did to fix the error when I had it.

Just remove

> activerecord-mysql2-adapter (0.0.3)

from your gemfile!

Hopefully that fixes it!

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)

Comment: This is after bundle updating mysql to the latest version (0.3.11)?

Comment: I have not update. I have just installed new version (there was no rails before on this computer - OSX)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why but when I add gem "mysql2", ">= 0.3.11"  and it works.
I have tried gem "mysql2", '0.3.2' and that was not working. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Glad you fixed it and it was just a gem versioning problem. So you know, 0.3.2 is the second version of 0.3 and 0.3.11 is the eleventh.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change `localhost to 127.0.0.1`. Please show your model, maybe some fields is the keyword of mysql

Comment: I have one table "users" with one field "name" ;)

Comment: Oh, I afraid some field is reverse word in mysql; but in this case, it isn't an issue:)

Answer (score 0):

please add the `port: 3306` to your database.yml, and `127.0.0.1` instead `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the earlier solutions mentioned:

- Get rid of the gem activerecord-mysql2-adapter
- Use gem mysql2 version 0.3.11 and above

It turned out there was simultaneously an older mysql2 gem installed, subtly throwing off my Rails app:

```
gem list
mysql2 (0.2.2, 0.3.17)

gem uninstall mysql --version=0.2.2
```

Finally after that uninstall, my app launched free of this error:

> /home/master/.rbenv/versions/2.5.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:408:in
>   `block (2 levels) in replace_gem': Please install the mysql2 adapter:`
>   gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~>
>   0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.2.2. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.) (LoadError)