# mysql compatability error - rake aborted error on rake db:create

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm a starter in ROR

I' m using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.1

This is what appears on using rake db:create command

```plain
**>rake db:create
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql adapter: 'gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter' <can't activate mysql <~> 2.8.1>, already activated mysql-2.9.0-x86-mingw32. Make sur all dependancies are added to Gemfile.>**
```

Have installed mysql gem and copied `libmysql.dll` file to `Ruby193/bin` (Phpmyadmin and xampp also works good).

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: it asks you for adapter from mysql to ror, not the mysql itself

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to add mysql2 gem into your Gemfile.

Take a look at this answer: [Rails mysql2 undefined method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730190/rails-mysql2-undefined-method-accept-for-nilnilclass/13787696#13787696)

If this doesn't solve your problem, paste the contents of your Gemfile.